# Issues with NSNotificationCenter in @IBAction function

Tags: xcode, swift, nsnotificationcenter, ibaction, nsnotification

I am working on an app that requires my main view controller to receive notifications from its child view controller. To do this, I set up the observer in the `viewDidLoad()` method of the parent controller, and I am trying to call the `postNotificationName()` function when a button is pressed that is located in the child view controller.

When the `postNotificationName()` call is located in the `@IBAction func buttonPressed(){ }` function, the observer never gets the notification. However, when the same code is called from a different function in the same view controller, it works.

I thought this might be a thread issue, and unsuccessfully tried many of the solutions for that issue. I'm not very familiar with threading, though, so maybe I still missed it. Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be?

Thanks for the help!

**ViewController**

```
class GameController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.init()


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "attemptHumanMove:", name: Constants.NSNotificationKey.tilePressed, object: nil)

}


func attemptHumanMove(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("test")
}
```

**ChildViewController**

```
@IBAction func tileTouched(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(Constants.NSNotificationKey.tilePressed, object: nil, userInfo: ["a": 0])
}
```

Comment: You're positive your IBAction method is getting called?

Comment: Yeah, have confirmed with breakpoints

Comment: Post your full code, from where you start listening for the notification to where you post it.

Comment: I think I posted all the necessary parts of the code. Hope this helps. There really isn't much to it.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that your addObserver isn't registering in time, or that one of them is being deallocated. I'm not sure aside from those suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting with the flow you have mentioned, the following code does receive the notification message from a child view controller.

### ParentViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var notificationMsgLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        notificationMsgLabel.text = "Waiting for notification..."
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "attemptHumanMove:", name: "tilePressed", object: nil)
    }

    func attemptHumanMove(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("Notification message received!")
        notificationMsgLabel.text = "Notification received!!!"
    }
}
```

### ChildViewController

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func sendNotification() {
        print("Sending notification message!!!")
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("tilePressed", object: nil, userInfo: ["a": 0])
    }
}
```

Here you can find the screen shot of the storyboard:
[Storyboard Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBQHS.png)